Nginx client_max_body_size not working in Docker container on AWS EC2 instance...gives 413 error
I am trying to increase the maximum size of file uploads from the default 1M to 100M (no size cap would also be acceptable). Despite declaring client_max_body_size 100M in multiple locations, I still get an error 413 (REQUEST ENTITY TOO LARGE). I tried parts of the solution in this post from 2014, but since it's 10 years old and specific to Elastic Beanstalk it didn't work.
My setup is deploying a simple Flask app in a Docker container (stored in AWS Elastic Container Registry), running within an AWS EC2 instance (Amazon Linux 2023 AMI, 64-bit ARM architecture).
Does anyone know how to increase the size limit for this setup?
Here are the relevant files:
Dockerfile
FROM debian:bookworm

# Create directory inside docker image
RUN mkdir app

# Update package manager (apt-get) and Python and Pip
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip

# update pip and necessary package handling tools
RUN pip install -U --break-system-packages \
    pip \
    setuptools \
    wheel

# copy requirements.txt from local to image
COPY requirements.txt /app/

# Install required packages
RUN pip install --break-system-packages -r /app/requirements.txt

# Copy over all necessary files for application
COPY ./ ./app/

# setup folder permissions
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data ./app/data_temp/
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data ./app/log/
RUN chmod +x ./app/data_temp/
RUN chmod +x ./app/log/
RUN chmod +x ./app/start.sh

# nginx config files
RUN apt-get install nginx -y
RUN mv /app/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/
RUN mv /app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
ENV CLIENT_MAX_BODY_SIZE=100M

# restart nginx server
RUN service nginx restart

# Expose a port so the app can be accessed from the web
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the app (Shell script launches a redis-server and then flask app)
CMD ["./app/start.sh"]

default
upstream flaskapp {
    server 0.0.0.0:8000;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://flaskapp;
        }

        client_max_body_size 100M;

        location ~ "/upload_label_data/([0-9a-zA-Z-.]*)$" {
                dav_methods  PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
                client_body_temp_path /tmp/incoming;
                alias     /home/ubuntu/app/data_temp/labels/incoming/$1;
                create_full_put_path   on;
                dav_access             group:rw  all:r;
                client_body_in_file_only on;
                client_body_buffer_size 128k;

                client_max_body_size 100M;

                proxy_pass_request_headers on;
                proxy_set_body $request_body_file;
                proxy_pass http://flaskapp/upload_label_data/$1;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
        keepalive_timeout 3600s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 3600s;
        proxy_send_timeout 3600s;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 3600s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
}

nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections  768; 
}

http {
        client_max_body_size 100M;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        gzip on;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

Thanks in advance for any help!

Do you see the client_max_body_size 100M; when dumping the configuration nginx -T?
